# get span class from HTML using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, aliexpress

I am trying to get the price from an AliExpress Product page using VBA.

However I am getting a runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set..
This is my Code:

```
Sub Get_Web_Data()


Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

' Website to go to.
website = "https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005002587077651.html"

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
price = html.getElementsByClassName("product-price-value").Item(0).innerText

' Output the price into a message box.
MsgBox price

End Sub
```

The code wors for other pages Like Yahoo Finance, i only get the problem for AliExpress.

Thank you.

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: Try `response = request.responseText` instead of `response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)`

Comment: Sidenote: there's really no need to comment every single line of code. Some line are self-explanatory and what you are doing makes your code harder to read.

Comment: The price is not saved as html value. It's part of an embeded JSON. But it seems that the JSON will addad dynamicaly to the page code. That means the price is not part of the document you load. Be aware: 1. xhr can only get one static file, no dynamic data. 2. There is no code which will load every page. You must programe it individually for every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx

```
Sub Get_Web_Data()

Dim reg As Object
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant


Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
reg.Pattern = "totalValue: ""US \$(.+)"""
website = "https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005002587077651.html"
Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
request.Open "GET", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00     GMT"
request.send
Set matches = reg.Execute(request.responseText)
MsgBox "US $" & matches.Item(0).submatches(0)

End Sub
```